# local notification updated with current time

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications

i created a dictionary with a date(key) and words (First - Second ..) like this :

```
let dict = ["23.08.2021":["First","number"],
      "24.08.2021":["second","number"],
      "25.08.2021":["third","number"]]
```

**i want the app send a local notifcation depneding on the currint date of the app !
if today is 25.08.2021 the app will send local notifcation with the word third as a title .**

What i did :

to get the currnt date i use this code :

```
let date3 = Date()
            let thirtyDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date3)! 
            let formatter3 = DateFormatter()
            formatter3.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            let result3 = formatter3.string(from: thirtyDay)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(result3, forKey:"nextDAY")
```

to save the key and the word from the dictionary :

```
    for (key, value) in dict {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value[0], forKey:"the number")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value[1], forKey:"the word")

        }
```

code :

```
func scheduleLocal() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = " #### what should i write here??? #######"
    content.body = "click here"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    TimeSet.datePickerMode = .time

    let date = TimeSet.date
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let hour = components.hour!
    let minute = components.minute!

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "X", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
    }
```

Comment: What is your question.  Or what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to send a local notification depending on the current date using your "scheduleLocal()" function,try something like this:

```
func scheduleLocal() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let todayKey = formatter.string(from: Date())
    
    if let title = dict[todayKey]?[0] {
        content.title = title
    } else {
        //   content.title = "what ever you want to send"
        // or don't send anything
        return
    }
    content.body = "click here"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    TimeSet.datePickerMode = .time
    
    let date = TimeSet.date
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let hour = components.hour!
    let minute = components.minute!
    
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "X", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

PS: your "thirtyDay" should probably be like this:

```
let thirtyDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: date3)!
```

Comment: if i dont open the app it keeps giving me the same title even in the next day

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry , the problem is when next day coming the notifcation still the same as day before , for examble : the Titlle for the date 23.08.2021 is First . the other day the app still send First not the other Title with the new date 24.08.2021

Comment: show us the real `scheduleLocal()` code you are using, in particular how you call this function in your app.

Comment: you could try: `let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)`  <--- here  to trigger the notification only once.